# Combine multiple rows into single row in SQL View (without group by or with CTE?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm trying to create complex view, when I have relation one to many then I want to put these value into single row.

Staff *(main table)*

```
ID            Name
1             aaa
2             bbb
```

OtherStaff *(table one to many)*

```
ID            StaffId       Name       Value
1             1             xxx        888
2             1             yyy        777
3             2             vvv        333
```

SomeTable *(table one to one)*

```
 Id          StaffId        SomeVal
 1           1              qwert
 2           2              asd
```

Result:

```
ID            Name          OtherStaff                SomeVal
1             aaa           xxx, 888; yyy, 777        qwert
2             bbb           vvv, 333                  asd
```

View:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT
    Staff.Id,
    MagicCombine(OtherStaff.Name, OtherStaff.Value) -- pseudocode
    SomeTable.SomeVal   
FROM 
    dbo.[Staff] Staff 
    JOIN dbo.[OtherStaff] OtherStaff ON OtherStaff.StaffId = Staff.Id
    JOIN dbo.[SomeTable] SomeTable ON SomeTable.StaffId= Staff.Id
```

I have read that I can use GroupBy but in fact I will have a lot of JOINS and Columns, **but GroupBy requires to put them all into clause**. I was thinking about more elegant solution? Can CTE – Common Table Expressions be useful somehow?

Comment: What you are doing *is* aggregation, you need to use a `GROUP BY`. I suggest having a look at `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine multiple rows into single row in SQL View with multiple joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400775/combine-multiple-rows-into-single-row-in-sql-view-with-multiple-joins) **Don't just ask the same question again, edit your original and try explain why it's not a duplicate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "magic function" would appear to be `STRING_AGG()`.

The code would then look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT Staff.Id,
           STRING_AGG(CONCAT(OtherStaff.Name, ', ', OtherStaff.Value), '; ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OtherStaff.Name),
           SomeTable.SomeVal   
    FROM dbo.[Staff] Staff JOIN
         dbo.[OtherStaff] OtherStaff
         ON OtherStaff.StaffId = Staff.Id JOIN
         dbo.[SomeTable] SomeTable
         ON SomeTable.StaffId = Staff.Id
    GROUP BY Staff.Id, SomeTable.SomeVal;
```

Listing unaggregated columns in both the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` should not be too troublesome.  After all, you can just cut-and-paste them.

Comment: I have error: `The function 'CONCAT' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.`

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis on Gordon's solution, @DiPix , and the column is also missing a alias.

Comment: True, I just found that